# How to find the entity specific named id?

Tags: entities

How do I map entity type to the entity specific named id, like this:

```
node => nid
taxonomy_term => tid
comment => cid
```

so that I can turn code like

```
 $entity->nid
```

into something like

```
$entity->{$label}
```

and correctly handle non-node entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (definitely works for all core entities, I don't have any custom entities to play with on my sandbox site I'm afraid):

```
$type = 'taxonomy_term';

// Get the entity type info
$info = entity_get_info($type);

// Grab the id key
$key = $info['entity keys']['id'];

// $key contains 'tid'
```

I'm pretty positive this will work across any entity type though, according to [`hook_entity_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7) the `id` property of `entity keys` is required:

> Every entity object passed to the Field API must have this property and its value must be numeric.